# How to use p-value as criteria in an ifelse statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, p-value

I'm trying to find a way to add a column to my data frame that classifies the values in two treatment groups as similar or different from a control depending if the values are statistically different from the control.

I'm not sure if that this is even possible, but let's asume I have some data similar to

```
df <- data_frame(species = rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), times = 12),
         condition = rep(c("Control", "Treat1", "Treat2"), each = 16),
         values = rep(c(rnorm(16, mean = 16, sd = 4),
                        rnorm(16, mean = 14, sd = 3),
                        rnorm(16, mean = 5, sd = 10))))
```

And now I want to add a column.
I was thinking about using something like

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(species) %>%
    mutate(new_column = ifelse("Value of each condition statistically different from Control", "Different", "Same")
```

So, is there a way to apply a statistical test inside a ifelse statement?

Or should I better use some easier criteria to classify the data. Maybe classify all values that come within ± 1 standard diviation of the control as "same"?

Thanks for your help and input.
I'm looking forward to reading your replies and suggestions.

Comment: Can you define more clearly what test you'd like to perform? Is this a oneway anova with some post-hoc testing? Also look at the `broom` package. It is glorious.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to research "t-tests" and their various assumptions. These are meant to determine if two samples from normal distributions have the same mean. The default in R is to assume that variances are not equal, which is good for your simulated set.

I'll skip the data wrangling

```
> set.seed(1)
> control <- rnorm(16, mean = 16, sd = 4)
> treat1 <- rnorm(16, mean = 14, sd = 3)
> treat2 <- rnorm(16, mean = 5, sd = 10)
> lapply(list(treat1,treat2), function(t) t.test(t,control)$p.value < 0.05)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE
```

So, for this simulated set of data, the t-test does not distinguish between treatment 1 and the control at a 5% significance level. With a different sample, it might, and for larger samples it more likely would.